# OUTPUT parameter returns a single row and not the entire column

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure as

```
create procedure p1
    @id  INT,
    @name varchar(20) OUTPUT
as
begin
    select @name = name 
    from table1 
    where id = @id;
end
```

on executing it, I simply get 1 single row as a value.

However if I do not use the output parameter as

```
create procedure p1
   @id  INT
as
begin
    select name from table1 where id = @id;
end
```

I get the entire column. Note: In my table a single id can have multiple values, so ideally it should return > 1 values even with the `OUTPUT` parameter.

Why do I just get 1 row when using the `OUTPUT` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't get "one row" you get one scalar value via the output parameter because that's what you declared its type to be. varchar is a scalar value type. If you want a row set you don't need to use a parameter for it.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it is impossible to get > 1 values when using an OUTPUT parameter?

Comment: For a stored procedure, you can get one value per output parameter. You could write a table valued function instead, but that's a different animal entirely.